# Create a config file with Windows Form

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a appconfig file into a directory with Windows Form.

I have tried to create a .txt file and it works, but how can I create a config file instead of a .txt
This is what I have so far:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\khaab\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ReadingXML\ReadingXML\bin\Debug\Customers\" + CustomerTextBox);
StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\khaab\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ReadingXML\ReadingXML\bin\Debug\Customers\app.config");
File.Close();
MessageBox.Show("You have successfully added a customer", "Customer added", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

I want now to create a Windows Folder Directory and inside this directory it will create automatically an app.config file

Comment: That won't compile.  What is `TextBox` doing there?

Comment: Add a textbox input to form for filename. then Path.COmbine(directory, input.Text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, get the textbox text:

```
StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\khaab\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ReadingXML\ReadingXML\bin\Debug\Customers\" + TEXTBOXNAME.text + ".config");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's working, but the created file will be saved as a FILE extension and I want it as a .config extension? How can I do that?

Comment: Is it possible to read all the files that I create in this directory to show it in a dropdown menu. So when the user create a .config file it will also be added in to the dropdown menu so the user can choose this .config file?

Comment: Yes if you write all files in a same directory, add this code string[] file_list = Directory.GetFiles("YOUR_PATH", "*.config"); This will load all files in that has ".config" extension. From that you can iterate the array and add to dropdown list.

Comment: thanks for your answer again, but I don't understand, because I am also very new with C#. Can you give an example please?

Comment: try this to load to combobox: string[] file_list = Directory.GetFiles(@"YOUR_PATH", "*.config");
            foreach (string file_name in file_list)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(file_name);
            }

Comment: I entered this code in the combobox, but when I click on it the combobox is empty.

Comment: Put that code inside form load event or any other events you want

Comment: Its working now, but I had it wrong. First I need to create a folder with the textbox what we did after we press create it should create a windows folder with name that we had inside the textbox and after we create that It should automatically create an app.config file inside the folder we created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136469/discussion-between-khaab-and-imsome1).

Answer (score 0):

create textbox named `textboxFileName` on your form. When user clicks on `CreateCustomerButton`, read filename (ie `filename.ext` or `somename.config`) from textbox and combine it  with your program's `.exe` location (which is written in `Application.ExecutablePath` variable). Alternatively, enter some other path in `destFolder` variable. (someting like `@"c:\temp`).

Also, you should check if user entered text in textboxFileName before trying to write.

```
private void CreateCustomerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textboxFileName.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter filename and try again.");
    }

    string destFolder = Application.ExecutablePath;
    string destination = Path.Combine(destFolder, textboxFileName.Text);
    StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter(destination);
    File.Write("Hi");
    File.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this will save the file as .txt extension, but I want to save it as an .config extension

Comment: whatever is written in textbox will be filename. If you want to control what user enters, or append something specific, you should write additional logic